# selecting indexed xpath in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

on the following url there are 3 score cards.

https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/?month=4&day=8&year=2023

I've tried many different variation of the xpaths to try and access the second one but the first one linking to the box score keeps being returned.

```
score_card = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='game_summary expanded nohover '])[2]/p/a"))).click()
```

I've tried many different ways of changing it and can't crack it! please help.

thank you
!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use brackets in your xpath.

Use `.//div[@class='game_summary expanded nohover '][2]/p/a` and it should work.
Check the attached image[image]

Comment: Thank you! But how do you know this? Everywhere I have seen when indicating and index uses brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the parentheses in the `xpath` expression.

`(//div[@class='game_summary expanded nohover '])[2]` is the second `<div>` with that class in the document, as opposed to

`//div[@class='game_summary expanded nohover '][2]` which is the second child of their respective parent element.